# Very strange: tub & shower blocked, but toilet and sink fine, and snake won't fix it

Tags: plumbing, bathtub

Here's a doozy that so confused my plumber he left without fixing the problem: the tub and shower are both backed up but are somehow connected, since water in one will cause bubbles and eventually, a little bit of water, to show up in the other. I put a snake down both (15 feet), but the clog wasn't fixed (there's more than 15 feet between the shower and tub -- it's two adjacent bathrooms). The sink and toilets drain instantly, and I can hear the water going down the pipe in the crawl space.

I'm guessing there is a T junction connecting the shower/tub to the main stack, and when I put the snake in, it just goes straight past the clog and towards the other shower/tub. (However, when the plumber put his 25 foot snake in, it didn't come out the other shower, which it theoretically should have).

Is there a snake that can turn corners that I can force down the T junction? How can I fix this?

Comment: Your plumber should have a scoping camera which they could had pushed into the pipe to see if they could find the blockage. If they don't then you may call around.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

I read elsewhere that you can try putting a garden hose down the vent and the water might clear it.  But if it's a sub vent, then the water will just run right past it.